# Visual Studio 2022 Toolbar Icon Size

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I would like to create a customized toolbar with larger icons in Visual Studio 2022 IDE, not Visual Studio Code. Currently using Community edition but would like to do the same for Professional or Enterprise editions.

It seems like you can only add toolbars and commands and change the order of command buttons but there is no way to increase the toolbar button sizes?

I tried the same for Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18, but it seems to share the same UI for toolbar customization with the same limiting options as VS2022.